# in TabControl Datagridview's DatagridViewCheckboxColumn doesnt refresh after calling method which is check all checkboxcells

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have one datagridview. In each tabpages, there are datagridview. Every datagridview has a one datagridviewcheckboxcolumn. I want to it which, the form when is loading, every datagridviewcheckboxcell are selected. But datagridviews are not refreshing.

[image]

thats are my codes.

```
            #region kalıp datagridview için veri okuma ve yükleme
            _dtk = new DataTable();
            _dtk.TableName = "Kalip";
            ExcelProcessing.ReadExcelFile(ref _dtk, "Kalip");
            _dtk = OrganizeDataGridView.ChangeDataTableType(ref _dtk);
            Dtg_kd.DataSource = _dtk;

            #endregion

            #region makine datagridview için veri okuma ve yükleme
            _dtm = new DataTable();
            ExcelProcessing.ReadExcelFile(ref _dtm, "Makine");
            _dtm = OrganizeDataGridView.ChangeDataTableType(ref _dtm);
            Dtg_m.DataSource = _dtm;

            #endregion

        #region datagridviewler için checkbox eklemesi            
        OrganizeDataGridView.AddCheckboxColumn(ref Dtg_kd, ref cbk);                     
        OrganizeDataGridView.AddCheckboxColumn(ref Dtg_m, ref cbm);           
        #endregion

       #region checkboxcolumn checked values
        OrganizeDataGridView.CheckColumn(ref Dtg_kd,true);
        #endregion
```

My checked function is:

```
public static void CheckColumn(ref DataGridView _dataGridView,bool checkValue)
    {
            #region checkbox'ların dolu gelmesi         
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _dataGridView.Rows)
            {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;               
            chk.Value = checkValue;               
            }

        #endregion
        _dataGridView.RefreshEdit();
    }
```

Comment: Tab control has a nasty way to stop the non-selected pages from refreshing. Maybe you can select each page before refreshing the DGVs..

Comment: @TaW I have used temporary solution. O have a counter. If DGV showed, counter incrementing. So counter is equel zero, it means first loading.. But in still, Im searching effective solution.